# multi threaded httpwebreqest using task.run drops out some requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to start multiple httpwebrequest's at the same time from the same machine. But the problem that I am facing is that some requests get dropped out. I am not sure why is this happening and how I would fix this.

```
    private async Task<string> getSomeDataasync(string url)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader readStream = null;

                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.CharacterSet))
                        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                    else
                        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                    return  await readStream.ReadToEndAsync();
                }
            }
        return "";
     }
```

And for the Task.Run I did the following:

```
        Task task1 = Task.Run(() => getSomeDataasync("www.example.com"));
        Task task2 = Task.Run(() => getSomeDataasync("www.example.com"));
        Task task3 = Task.Run(() => getSomeDataasync("www.example.com"));
        Task task4 = Task.Run(() => getSomeDataasync("www.example.com"));
        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3, task4);
```

update:
I am using about 30 tasks.run in my application

Update:
I have tried this with different sites and each time I get different results.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dropped out"?

Comment: I figured out the problem its because that all what I needed to do is to add the key word await to the waitall of whenall and what I exactly did is that I created a list of methods that I need to call so that they get executed in parallel